# Ejecutar ciclo while varias veces una vez terminado

Tags: php, html

Buenas tardes, sé que mi pregunta no está muy clara, pero en está sección me explicaré mejor, sucede que tengo una tabla que queda así

[image: Imagen]

pero quiero que los input radio estén en todas las filas, este es mi código:

```
echo "<table class='table table-hover'>
<tbody>";
while($alum = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)){
echo "<tr>
    <th>".$alum['nombre_completo']."</th>";

    while($asis = mysql_fetch_row($res)){

    echo "<td> <input type='radio' name='asistencia' id='asistencia'           value='".$asis[0]."'><strong> ".$asis[1]."</strong></td>";
    }
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</tbody>
</table>";
```

el while que está dentro solo se ejecuta una vez y es lógico a mi parecer, pero quiero saber como hacer para que cada vez que inicie el primer while se ejecute también el while interior, tantan veces como se ejecute el primer while, espero haberme expresado lo mejor posible, muchas gracias.

Comment: Si ambos datos vienen, como se puede ver, de la base de datos, ¿por qué no haces un solo `SELECT` con todo lo que quieres y luego lo presentas en pantalla en vez de armar un rompecabezas más tarde para presentar los datos?

Comment: Yo creo que debería hacer una función la cual le imprima los radio button, y por cada registro llama una vez a esa función

Comment: Muéstranos las queries `$res2` y  `$res`. Ojo, estás imprimiendo varios radio con el mismo ID. Eso no es válido

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que en cada fila quieres la colección de 4 radio buttons, y tu consulta `$res` arroja cuatro resultados:

```
$asis_buttons='';
while($asis = mysql_fetch_row($res)){
    $asis_buttons.= "<td><input type='radio' name='asistencia' id='asistencia' value='".$asis[0]."'><strong> ".$asis[1]."</strong></td>";
}

echo "<table class='table table-hover'><tbody>";
while($alum = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)){
  echo "<tr><th>".$alum['nombre_completo']."</th>";
  echo $asis_buttons;
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</tbody></table>";
```

Pero igual esa solución no te va a funcionar como esperas. Tu fila de radio buttons tiene el mismo `id` para todos los elementos, y estarán en todas las filas. Sería mejor hacer una plantilla en donde pudieras reemplazas el `id` y nombre del alumno usando  `sprintf`:

```
<?php

$asistencias = [[1,'presente'],[2,'ausente'],[3,'desaparecido'],[4,'aparecido']];
$alumnos=['pedro','juan','diego'];
$asis_buttons='<tr><th>Alumno %1$s</th>';
foreach($asistencias as $asis){
    $asis_buttons.= '<td><input type="radio" name="asistencia%2$d" id="asistencia_'.$asis[0].'_%2$d" value="'.$asis[0].'"><strong>'.$asis[1].'</strong></td>';
}
$asis_buttons.='</tr>';


echo '<table>';
foreach($alumnos as $index=>$alumno) {
  echo sprintf($asis_buttons,$alumno,$index);
}
echo '</table>';
```